# What `null` size means in Framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php?

Tags: magento2, database, column, ddl

I refer to [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6d47e72c57025a8dd2bea8fef196f8397233c9c8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php) file, function `addColumn`

I need to confirm whether I have understood correctly or not the `null` value of field `size`. When I set `size` `null` , does this mean that the index's size will be set by the maximum size of the current table's data? 
If not, please explain. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass $size as **null** then it's take default value.

[Check following code sample](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6d47e72c57025a8dd2bea8fef196f8397233c9c8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php#L312)

```
case self::TYPE_NUMERIC:
    $match = [];
    $scale = 0;
    $precision = 10;
    // parse size value
    if (is_array($size)) {
        if (count($size) == 2) {
            $size = array_values($size);
            $precision = $size[0];
            $scale = $size[1];
        }
    } elseif (preg_match('#^(\d+),(\d+)$#', $size, $match)) {
        $precision = $match[1];
        $scale = $match[2];
    }
    // check options
    if (isset($options['precision'])) {
        $precision = $options['precision'];
    }

    if (isset($options['scale'])) {
        $scale = $options['scale'];
    }

    if (!empty($options['unsigned'])) {
        $unsigned = true;
    }
    break;
case self::TYPE_DATE:
case self::TYPE_DATETIME:
case self::TYPE_TIMESTAMP:
    break;
case self::TYPE_TEXT:
case self::TYPE_BLOB:
case self::TYPE_VARBINARY:
    $length = $size;
```

Here default value of $precision is 10.

Check following code

```
case self::TYPE_VARBINARY:
    $length = $size;
```

If $size is **null**, $length is also **null** but check following code what happened

[Click here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6d47e72c57025a8dd2bea8fef196f8397233c9c8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php#L2398)

[Updated]

[Check following code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6d47e72c57025a8dd2bea8fef196f8397233c9c8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php#L2396)

```
case Table::TYPE_TEXT:
case Table::TYPE_BLOB:
case Table::TYPE_VARBINARY:
```

That means type text, blob and varbinary takes default value if you pass size as a null. Default value is 1024

Comment: Yes, I had seen that in `TYPE_NUMERIC` default is 10, but what about `TYPE_TEXT`?
[Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6d47e72c57025a8dd2bea8fef196f8397233c9c8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php#L2398) is a special case for `TYPE_VARBINARY`.

I need some detail on `TYPE_TEXT` if you know. Thanks!

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Thank you! What about the final type on the database. Is a 1024 sized `TYPE_TEXT` saved as varchar, whereas a 1000000 sized `TYPE_TEXT` saved as text?